# How can I switch between cinemachine free look cameras by script?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class CamerasManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CinemachineFreeLook[] freeLookCameras;
    public float timeBeforeSwitching;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SwitchCameras(timeBeforeSwitching));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    IEnumerator SwitchCameras(float TimeBeforeSwitching)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeBeforeSwitching);

        for(int i = 0; i < freeLookCameras.Length; i++)
        {
            freeLookCameras[i].en
        }
    }
}
```

If I have two or more cameras I want that after X seconds start switching between all the cameras in the array by disabling/enable the cameras. disable the first enable the second then disable the second enable the third and so on.

Comment: It looks like you stopped writing that code partway through the `freeLookCameras[i].en...` line. What happens when you finish your thought and write the rest of the function you had in mind? Does anything go wrong?

Comment: @DMGregory not sure what the line should be.  Maybe like this freeLookCameras[i].enabled = true; but then how do I disable enabled false the camera before in the array?

Comment: What you want to manipulate is the cameras' priority. The highest priority takes control. Faffing about with the activation state of gameobjects and components works, but is a fool's errand once your system gets anywhere near the point of being complicated enough where using cinemachine actually makes sense.

Comment: If you want to access the previous camera in the array you can use `freeLookCameras[i-1]`.